# CMPedometerData.distance ... how is this calculated?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios8, core-motion

I have an app that uses CMStepCounter in iOS7. I am updating it to use the new APIs in iOS 8, primarily CMPedometer. CMPedometer's new handler returns an object called CMPedometerData which has distance, speed, and number of steps instead of just number of steps like CMStepCounter had. This is great but I maw wondering if anybody knows how apple calculates distance.

Previously I had to calculate distance by taking the number of steps and multiplying by the distance per step which I obtained from a user input stride length. People of different sizes will have different stride lengths and will travel different distances for the same number of steps. So I was wondering if Apple just takes this into account, or if they just use a hard coded stride length for everybody. IF anybody has figured this out, I would really like to know. Thanks!

Comment: I wondered the same - it seems to just assume 1 step = 83cm so far as I can tell

Comment: Have you checked for multiple users? I wonder if it uses the height you entered in health book.

Comment: CoreMotion differentiates between running and walking activity, and Health shows distance as "Walking + Running Distance", so I'm guessing they at the very least have a step length that varies based on what kind of activity it thinks you are doing.

Comment: I think you are right, it at least should use a different stride length for walking and running. I wonder if it uses the data in Health Book (height, weight, gender etc) to estimate stride. I haven't tested this yet.